# Can an HTML5 database exist between sessions?

Tags: javascript, database, html, cookies

Is it possible for an HTML5 database to exist between sessions, similar to how cookies can be persistent? If so, how is this done?

I need to replace cookie storage with something more robust, but it needs to exist between sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe localStorage is what you are looking for:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

EDIT: Updated dead link

Comment: Super easy to implement! I'm now using it instead of cookies, and falling back to cookies if localStorage isn't available.